# How to generate form from MongoDB in meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I want to generate a form from the Mongo Db entry in meteor

The DB entry contains the following parameters:

```
TemplateForm : [
                Template_Name: {type :String
                                Size : 20 
                               }
                Template_Date :{type : Date
                                Size : 8
                               }
]
```

Comment: You probably should take a look at [`aldeed:autoform`](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform) ([demo](http://autoform.meteor.com/)).

Answer (score 0):

Combine [autoform](https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/autoform) with [simple-schema](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema).

You'll be able to create a schema like this:

```
TemplateSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  ...
  'Name': {
    type: String,
    max: 20
  },
  ...
});
```

And then generate it automatically with autoform.

Comment: how to use autoform-id in html?